# Invalid android_key parameter. The key hash does not match any allowed key

Tags: android, facebook

I am having problem with facebook that if I am using my app first time then login from facebook app is successfully which is installed in device and then i logged out from my app and try to login again then the facebook error is showing like this...anyone faced this problem? Please help me..Thanks

**Invalid android_key parameter. The key hash does not match any allowed key.**

Comment: can you post some code? Also, what version of the Facebook app are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App is misconfigured for Facebook login : Android Facebook integration issue](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue)

Comment: I am using the latest facebook sdk..

Comment: no its not a duplicate Igy , 2 completely different errors.

Comment: When you log out, does it kill your Facebook session? And is your Facebook app in sandbox mode? If your app is in sandbox mode, it won't let you complete auth unless you're logged into FB first.

Comment: I think it will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435441/getting-invalid-android-key-parameter-error-after-first-time-login-in-facebook

Comment: @user898738 I did same thing but no luck. It's not working yet.

Comment: @user2461490 My app is not in sandbox mode.

Comment: @MehulRanpara have you solved this.If So Please provide a solution.Thanks

Comment: @hemanthkumar I solved this issue by generating hash key programatically..