# Getting invalid android_key parameter error, after first time login in Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, hash, key, facebook-android-sdk

I have got the hash key from my debug store using

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore C:\Users\user.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e

and pasted the key to Facebook App for Android and also enabled "Facebook Login" option.

When I first time log into my Android App, it shows me a permission dialog and after giving the permission, I am enable to get me details from Facebook.

But after that when i exit and the app and again open and try to login, it shows below screen.

I don't get this, if hash key is the issues, then why it works in first attempt.

I am using facebook sdk old version not the new 3.+ version.

[image: Error when attempting second login]

Comment: See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979389/android-invalid-key-and-facebook-connect

Comment: @kaibuki have you solved this problem...i m facing the same problem.Please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved the issues, added permission of "offline_access" and also the Hashkey should match the key which appears in error.
Use "Key Hash" apk available at Easy Facebook SDK website, install it on phone to get the HASH KEY or use KEYTOOL plugin to get the SHA1 of your keystore and then convert it to base64 from **[here](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en)**. and *add this key to your register project*.. :)
Hope this helps @Pratick

Comment: can you provide link for "Key Hash" apk available at Easy Facebook SDK website.thanks!

Comment: @kaibuki Can you please illustrate your answer in steps and not depending on any thirdparty apk. waiting...

Comment: Really amazing solution

Answer (score -1):

key hash generate via code and paste on facebook apps setting key hash . 100% will be solved . The code is

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.matainja.facebooklogin", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmExceptio`enter code here`n e) {

    }
```

replace the package name .

Comment: This code generates the same keyhash i have on facebook apps, and it doesn't solve the problem.